# Change VS build folder to the same folder (windows form and console)

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, console

I have a product composed by some different files:

1. Some windows form applications (windows form + .net5).
2. Some console applications (.net5)
3. Some class libraries shared by them (.net5)
4. Some json data used by them.

I changed all of the build output folders to "W:\Cci", but it turned out that they are not in the exactly place:

1. All windows form applications will be put in: "W:\Cci\net5.0-windows"
2. All console applications will be put in : "W:\Cci\net5.0"

Which means they cannot share json data files.

I know that there is a "Publish" function might do the job, but I want to debug them in the same folder as well.

Anyone can help? thanks.

Comment: What if you would add the JSON files as existing items/as link to all the projects that need them?

Comment: @WouterdeKort But I really like them to be in a same folder, so I can just copy/zip them with one click.

Comment: @cheny, do you consider that create a shared project and put the json files in the shared project? Then you can access the jsons for every project.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT yes I thought of that. But the json files are generated by one of the win form with dynamic names, and their content are very different each time. So they are not there at compiling time. Now I have changed the console app to a win form app temporarily, with most of the code in a library which can be reused by the console in the future. Another solution is to run win form apps in Linux, so I do not need to move back to console. Seems there are some other answers for it. But the question is still there, because some of these apps are design to be run as backend commands.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. In the Solution Explorer.
2. Expend your-solution-name(the project)/Dependencies/Projects.
3. Right click "Projects" and select "Add Project Reference".
4. Select the dlls.
5. Build the solution.

After that, the .net dlls appear both in W:\Cci\net5.0 and W:\Cci\net5.0-windows.